# C# - Advantages of System.Threading.Monitor to control thread

Tags: c#

As  lock is the  indirect representation of System.Threading.Monitor ,incase if i wish to directly use the Monitor could i achieve any additional benefits.(I have read an articles ,it suggests always use Monitor to get additional benefits.But there is no explanation of those benefits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `lock` only calls `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`, so if you *restrict* yourself to `lock` you won't be able to use other useful features like `Monitor.Wait`, `Monitor.Pulse`, etc. Otherwise there isn't really any disadvantage to using `lock` instead of manually using `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`, and `lock` does have the advantage that it automatically puts the appropriate code in a try-finally block.

Answer (score 10):

The `lock` statement is syntactic sugar on the `Enter` and `Exit` methods of the Monitor class.

You can still use `Pulse` and `Wait` as follows:

```
lock(x) {
    Monitor.Pulse(x);
    Monitor.Wait(x);
}
```

You must (at least to my knowledge) use Monitor directly if you want to use the non-blocking [TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter.aspx) method.

I don't agree with the assertion that you should *always* use `Monitor`; the `lock` keyword is convenient when you just need to do what it offers.

Answer (score 3):

The Monitor class implements the monitor synchronization primitive: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29. As you can see its not really .Net/C# idea, its widely known concept - taught as part of any Computing degree. It offers you not only ability to lock the critical section, but also provides implementation of queues internal for the given instance - which enables to have much more complicated interaction between threads.

Regarding what you should use, the answer is usually the simplest method that does the job - which in >90% cases would be to just use the `lock(sth){...}` syntax.